# Reuse identity value after deleting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, identity

Is it possible to reuse an identity field value after deleting rows in SQL Server 2008 Express? Here is an example. Suppose I have a table with an Id field as a primary key (identity). If I add five rows, I will have these 5 Ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If I were to delete these rows, and then add five more, the new rows would have Ids: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Is it possible to let it start over at 1 again?

Do I have to delete data from another table in order to accomplish this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean identity field? The primary key for almost all my tables is ID and that is usually (though not exclusively) an identity field

Comment: Yes, I meant an identity field.

Comment: Just because there is a way to do this doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the following to set the IDENTITY value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, RESEED, 999)
```

That means you'll have to run the statement based on every DELETE.  That should start to highlight why this is a bad idea...

The database doesn't care about sequential values - that's for presentation only.

Comment: If you want to insert a row with ID 10 you should reseed with ID 9. Assuming the increment is 1.

Comment: You can also use this in order to find out your current seed value:  select ident_current('table_name') as current_identity

Answer (score 11):

If you want to reset the identity after deleting *all* rows then do one of these

```
--instead of delete, resets identity value
TRUNCATE TABLE orders

--or if TRUNCATE fails because of FKs, use this after DELETE
DBCC CHECKIDENT (orders, RESEED, 1)
```

Otherwise, the internal value should not matter whether gaps or not.

Answer (score 7):

`identity` fields do not reuse old values by default.  You can reseed them with [`dbcc checkident`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx), but this isn't suggested as you will get key violations if you reseed below a value that still exists in the table.  In general, you shouldn't care what the PK values are.  The fact that they're not contiguous doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: The fact that they are not continuous actually does hurt something, because deleted values are not reused.  Since a 32-bit identity column would be limited to a maximum of 2^32 (or 2^31 if excluding negative values) inserts and deletes, after which inserts would cause an overflow error.  It's essentially a kind of resource leak.  I did a few calculations and determined that a 32-bit identity column is not future-proof, and even a 64-bit column may not be enough, since a computer only 1000 or so times faster than my desktop could eat up the values in less than a year.  So 128-bit GUIDs FTW.

Comment: Using a bigint as the identity column gets you 2^63 - 1 rows. That is 9 quintillion rows. Even at a trillion inserts per day, this will still last you 25,000 years.

Comment: > "The fact that they are not continuous actually does hurt something, because deleted values are not reused".
You'll quickly regret this if a deleted key value was stored somewhere else and is now pointing to the wrong data.