# c# entity frame work how to set automatic ID value after delete a row

Tags: c#

I'm working with entity framework.

How do I set an automatic ID when I delete a record?

Eg.:

I deleted a record with ID = 5

How do I set the second ID = 5, not = 6?

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DataID { set; get; }

    public string FName { set; get; }

    public string LName { set; get; }

    public string FaName { set; get; }
```

i talk about DataID

and this is the function who i delete the record

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              using (ScoutContext db = new ScoutContext())
                {
                   var toBeDeleted = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
                    var userdata = db.ScoutDatas.First(c => c.DataID == toBeDeleted);
                    db.ScoutDatas.Remove(userdata);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
             }
        }
```

I need like this but in c#

```
declare @max int
select @max=max([DataID])from [ScoutDatas]
if @max IS NUll   
  SET @max = 0
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[ScoutDatas]', RESEED,@max)
```

Comment: is this an auto increment ? show you model class and dbcontext class please .

Comment: Modifying the primary key of existing records is rarely a good idea in relational database systems.

Comment: why -1 ? isn't a good question ?

Comment: in SQL column which has auto increment key, even if you delete all records, the next insert will have incremented index and will not start with 1. It will only start with 1 if you truncate the table. If you still need this type of feature, you can write your own logic to insert value of your choice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse identity value after deleting rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288089/reuse-identity-value-after-deleting-rows)

Comment: SQL Server does not charge by the ID issued. Feel free to use all the integers you need - the ID values should not be relevant to the users anyhow.

Comment: Have you thought about all foreign key relationship of record? once you remove this record, other related tables will be linked to a wrong record if you haven't considered updating them as well.

Comment: No man, it's helpless for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe its work

```
var toBeDeleted = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
            var userdata = db.ScoutDatas.Where(c => c.DataID >= toBeDeleted).Take(2).ToList();
            db.ScoutDatas.Remove(userdata[0]);
            userdata[1].DataID = toBeDeleted;
            db.SaveChanges();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Yes Man it's work , but after that the IDValue to the rest of table will be incorrect,
so i need to reset automatic increment of ID to the rest of table

Comment: houhouuu pleaseeee

Comment: If you want to update all, you can remove .Take(2).
and you need a for loop for result. But I dont suggest this way.
I downt know, you gonna use it where. maybe row number is more easy.