# Reuse the deleted row's identity value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to reuse an identity field value after deleting rows in SQL Server 2008 Express? Here is an example. Suppose I have a table with an Id field as a primary key (identity). If I add five rows, I will have these 5 Ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. If I were to delete these rows, and then add five more, the new rows would have Ids: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Is it possible to let it start over at 1 again?

Do I have to delete data from another table in order to accomplish this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want this requirement?

Comment: just curious. i am a beginner in programming.

Comment: identity columns should be treated as *opaque blobs* that just happen to fit in numeric columns. The system guarantees to make them unique. So long as that's all you use them for, you'll be fine. As soon as you start *caring* about the *actual* numerical values, you'll start going wrong.

Comment: Just don't. You are setting yourself up for a ton of hurt.

Comment: It's possible but pointless. As Damien wrote - identity columns (and in fact, every surrogate key) should not have business meaningful values. Their sole purpose is to provide an easy-to-use row identifier. Please note that they should also **not** replace natural keys - When using an identity column as your table's primary key, you must also provide a unique index (or constraint) on the column (or columns) that make up your natural key.

Comment: If you are deleting all the rows, use `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead.  This will re-set the seed for your `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: The question is a complete copy of [Reuse identity value after deleting rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288089/reuse-identity-value-after-deleting-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to reuse an identity field value after deleting rows in SQL Server 2008 Express?

Yes, ***but it's one of the worst decisions you could make***.

This is so bad that I'm not gonna explain how to do it, but just why this is bad.

We use identity columns to generate values that are unrelated to the data the table holds.

- If we use identities as primary keys and we reuse their value, the same key will hold 2 (or more) different entities throughout time, giving place to confusion specially when generating reports or having other tables that use this key and don't have referential integrity.
- Solutions used to identify unused values (infamous gaps and islands problem) are very slow when the amount of rows increase. This makes performance drop as rows piles up.
- You will have to apply this "unused number" logic every time you insert rows on the table, so it's another thing to keep in mind on maintenance tasks.
- There is little to none benefit of reusing these numbers as `INT` or `BIGINT` max values are high enough to support most business data.
- It's common to use identities as primary keys or with a clustered index because new records will be inserted at the end, reducing fragmentation. Once records are deleted, it generates gaps in between pages (the swiss cheese pages), which is solved by doing index rebuilds. The problem comes after the rebuilds, where you will be potentially inserting new records massively in between and cause tons of page splits, hitting performance unnecessarily.

I can't possible think of a real case when you actually need to fill empty gaps in an identity column, as the purpose of this value is to be unrelated to the entity the table represents.

Comment: Surrogate identity column, no (they're the equivalent of memory addresses).  Rarely, you need to ensure natural keys are gapless (invoices being one), but key reuse in such a case would be even worse.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to remove all the data inside the table you can use [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which will help you remove whole data in table and reset the identity to start from the SEED value.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable
```

You can also use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to reseed your identity to the spesific value.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.MyTable', RESEED, 1);
```

The following code will reed the identity to start from 1.

Finally, if you need to cover the gaps, you need to know that, using IDENTITY you are mot able to cover the gaps, and you need to implement your custom function to behave like IDENTITY and cover the gaps.

Comment: "you need to implement your custom function to behave like IDENTITY and cover the gaps." That's probably the worst advice you can give. Attempting to create your own auto-increment mechanism is bound to fail, especially in multi-threaded or multi-users environments.

Comment: You can use SEQUENCE to implement that function which will help you write the above mentioned function

Comment: Only in 2012 version or higher, but that would also not solve the gaps problem. In fact, I suspect that the same mechanism that generates the identity values is also responsible of generating sequences (though SQL Server is not open source so I can't *know* that).

Answer (score -1):

We can do this by two ways.

If it is Non Pk Column, Insert the record with same Identity number then delete the previous identity column value.

If you don't need owl data drop the table and recreate that table or truncate the table and use DBCC CHECKIDENT to reseed your identity to the spesific value.

Answer (score -2):

Possible if you remove `Autoincrement` attribute from `ID`.

You can keep a check if the table is empty or not and `INSERT` values accordingly.

Comment: This means you will now have to build code to perform this checking for you. Every time you would do an INSERT, that code will first have to check that the chain of numbers is unbroken, or fill in the first "empty" gap. Performance-wise, you'll be hurting very quickly. It is much easier simply letting the identity column determine the next value. After all, id-fields are not supposed to be used for containing business-logic, but rather they provide an easy entry point to uniquely identify a row.

Comment: @SchmitzIT Obviously it has poor performance. Either you have to do this or you have to keep a track of what is the condition of the table (either empty or the last value has been deleted) in another table or you have to fetch the preceding value of the ID that you are inserting. Whatever you do nothing will be as smooth as autoincrement attribute. The question itself lacks merit in terms of application but to learn one can try several techniques.

Comment: Sure. However, considering the OPs first comment "I'm a beginner in programming", I figured pointing out why everyone thinks it's a bad idea. I agree it could be a fun challenge, just for the sake of coding it, but for a beginner, just no.